# Error compiling visp_vision

Tags: ros, visp-auto-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Getting the following error when making visp. Any idea on how to resolve this? visp_bridge was installed via ubuntu  software center and rosdep install visp_bridge was also run in terninal.

[

```
 95%] [ 95%] Building CXX object vision_visp/visp_auto_tracker/CMakeFiles/auto_tracker.dir/flashcode_mbt/libauto_tracker/threading.cpp.o
Building CXX object vision_visp/visp_auto_tracker/CMakeFiles/auto_tracker.dir/flashcode_mbt/libauto_tracker/tracking.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/visp_hand2eye_calibration_client.dir/src/client.cpp.o: In function `visp_hand2eye_calibration::Client::initAndSimulate()':
client.cpp:(.text+0x2a27): undefined reference to `visp_bridge::toGeometryMsgsTransform(vpHomogeneousMatrix&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x2b0a): undefined reference to `visp_bridge::toGeometryMsgsTransform(vpHomogeneousMatrix&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x36ac): undefined reference to `visp_bridge::toGeometryMsgsTransform(vpHomogeneousMatrix&)'
```

Output on find for visp_bridge

```
richard:catkin_ws$ sudo find ./ -name *visp_bridge*
./build/vision_visp/visp_bridge
./build/vision_visp/visp_bridge/CMakeFiles/visp_bridge.dir
./build/vision_visp/visp_bridge/catkin_generated/installspace/visp_bridgeConfig-version.cmake
./build/vision_visp/visp_bridge/catkin_generated/installspace/visp_bridgeConfig.cmake
./build/vision_visp/visp_bridge/catkin_generated/installspace/visp_bridge.pc
./build/vision_visp/visp_bridge/catkin_generated/stamps/visp_bridge
./src/vision_visp/visp_bridge
./src/vision_visp/visp_bridge/include/visp_bridge
./devel/share/visp_bridge
./devel/share/visp_bridge/cmake/visp_bridgeConfig-version.cmake
./devel/share/visp_bridge/cmake/visp_bridgeConfig.cmake
./devel/lib/libvisp_bridge.so
./devel/lib/pkgconfig/visp_bridge.pc
./devel/lib/visp_bridge
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221327/error-compiling-visp_vision/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why do you install it by source? If you have Indigo or Jade, you could just install it from the repositories:

sudo apt-get install ros-jade-visp

---

Originally posted by [rossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4597/rossi/) with karma: 73 on 2015-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-11-27**:
yes ... just found this out .... after I trashed my system and reinstalled from indigo to jade. Thanks for you answer.